# Validate Form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to Validate my form in Codeigniter. I have seen many tutorials but not getting what i want. If the fields are blank then i have to show error message and be on the 
same page and if the field are filled then i want to submit the data and after submitting successfully the 
register_view.php should be visible with message of User Successfully Registered, but here validation is not 
working.

> register_view.php

```
<?php echo form_open('register/user_register'); ?>
   <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><?php $inusername=array('name' => 'username', 'class' => 'GUI'); echo form_input($inusername); ?></td>
                    <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><?php $inpassword=array('name' => 'password', 'class' => 'GUI', 'type' =>'password'); echo form_input($inpassword); ?></td>
                    <td class="error"><?php echo form_error('password'); echo $this->session->flashdata('login'); ?></td>
                </tr>
   </table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

> Register.php

```
<?php
class Register extends Controller {

    function Register(){
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            /*  Show error messages     */
        }else{

            $username=$this->input->post('username');
            $password=$this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->view('success');
                        $data=array('username' => $this->security->xss_clean($username),'password'=> $this->security->xss_clean($password));

                        $result = $this->register_user_model->register_user_model($data); 
                        redirect('register');
                }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');`;
`

Comment: what exactly is the error??

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller).

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // YOU GET HERE WHEN THERE IS NO DATA SUBBMITTED OR WHEN YOU VALIDATION WAS INVALID
    $this->load->view('myform');
}
else
{
    // YOU GET HERE WHEN YOUR VALIDATION WAS VALID, SO YOU CAN SAVE DATA TO YOUR DATABASE AND SHOW A SUCCESSPAGE.
    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```

It seems you are mixing that up in your code, so it won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use version 2+ at least, you should refactor your code.
Try with changing

```
function Register(){
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

with

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to do it. It is as follows:

- In Controller:

  ```
  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){


      $data['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>Some error</div>';
      $this->load->view('register', $data);


  }
  ```
- And in view do like this:

  ```
  <?php if(isset($msg)){echo $msg ;} ?>
  ```

You can have different error messages like `$msg_username` or whatever.

Hope this is helpful.